# laravel how to get JSON value from an input

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js

I have an input item with value set as json, because I want to later get this value in controller, but I just get [object, object]

the JSON is:

```
    [{
    "title": "G30 BMW 530d is Victoria Police's new patrol car - 80 units to join fleet by end-2018, all with 'police pack'",
    "url": "https://paultan.org/2017/09/20/g30-bmw-530d-is-victoria-police-new-patrol-car/",
    "thumbnail": "https://s1.paultan.org/image/2017/09/VP_HWP_Bmw_530D_Front_side.jpg",
    "source": "Paul Tan's Automotive News",
    "source_url": "https://paultan.org/2017/09/20/g30-bmw-530d-is-victoria-police-new-patrol-car/",
    "date_published": "2017-09-20",
    "provider": "Event Registry",
    "provider_url": "http://eventregistry.org"
}, {
    "title": "Opel Astra GSi Spied Nearly Naked",
    "url": "http://gmauthority.com/blog/2017/09/opel-astra-gsi-spied-nearly-naked/",
    "thumbnail": "http://gmauthority.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Opel-GSi-Teaser-1024x771.jpg",
    "source": "GM Authority",
    "source_url": "http://gmauthority.com/blog/2017/09/opel-astra-gsi-spied-nearly-naked/",
    "date_published": "2017-09-19",
    "provider": "Event Registry",
    "provider_url": "http://eventregistry.org"
}]
```

Vuejs

```
<div v-for="article in articles_sortByDate" v-bind:key="article.id">
    <input type="checkbox"
          :value="article" 
           v-model="checkedArtcles"  
           name='checkedArtcles'>
</div>
```

Now if I try to get this value from controller with

```
dd($request->input('checkedArtcles'));

//this results in [Object, object]
```

Have also tried:

```
dd(json_decode($request->input('checkedArtcles')));

//this return NUll
```

Comment: Please provide working example . live demo in snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your javascript logic (in this case vue) parse your json to string, then append to select's value, then in controller you can try to acces `$request->input('checkedArtcles')` or dd that.

Comment: I think that the problem is that $request->input('') is changing json to string and hence getting object, object. I have tried your solution and it returns error Call to a member function toArray() on string

Comment: so it means $request->input('checkedArtcles') is a string, can you show me the source code generated by the vue, ctrl+u while on your page that displaying the select, may be it is because its value already string with value 'object'.

Comment: you might be right here is what I get in the cource <span class=sf-dump-str title="47 characters">[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]</span>"
</pre>

Comment: yes I've already done that but now the problem is that the value is not right for json_decode I can see it as a string there "{"title":"Peugeot-Citroen strikes deal with GM to buy Vauxhall-Opel","url":"http://p.dw.com/p/2YgXx","thumbnail":"https://api.dw.com/image/37545225_301.jpg" like so but json_decode returns null

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an object, decode the string, but add `true` to give you an associative array:

`$array = json_decode($string, true);`

See here for more details http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Where is this JSON string coming from?

Comment: the json string is coming from data in vue.js compoennt

Comment: echo it out wherever you grab it in your controller and var dump it to make sure you got the string correctly

Comment: echo also just returns [object Object]